# How to merge and duplicate observations and variables in Stata?

Tags: stata, panel-data

I need to convert my data set to a panel dataset, but I couldn't find anything how to do it both in Stata help and Google. My data looks like this:

### [A]  [B]  [C]  [D]  [E]

### [1]  [1]  [0]  [10] [12]

### [2] [0] [0] [13] [14]

### [3] [1] [1] [15] [17]

A is student id and D and E are their test scores in two different years. So, I need the data to look like this:

### [A]   [B]  [C] [(D and E)]

### [(D)1] [1] [0] [10]

### [(E)1] [1] [0] [12]

### [(D)2] [0] [0] [13]

### [(E)2] [0] [0] [14]

### [(D)3] [1] [1] [15]

### [(E)3] [1] [1] [17]

Comment: This is massively documented. The panel and data management  documentation are both extensive. You should at least attempt code. The data examples are clear but the square brackets `[ ]` have no Stata meaning here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to skim the headings of the data management manual, [D] or https://www.stata.com/manuals/d.pdf, to find relevant commands. The immediate small problem here is poorly chosen variable names -- at least in your data example; we can't tell if you're using more sensible names in your real data. Then your new data layout is a simple application of `reshape long`.

```
clear 
input A  B  C  D  E
1  1  0  10 12
2 0 0 13 14
3 1 1 15 17
end 

rename A id 
rename (D E) (mark2015 mark2016) 

reshape long mark, i(id) j(year) 

list, sepby(id) 

     +--------------------------+
     | id   year   B   C   mark |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |  1   2015   1   0     10 |
  2. |  1   2016   1   0     12 |
     |--------------------------|
  3. |  2   2015   0   0     13 |
  4. |  2   2016   0   0     14 |
     |--------------------------|
  5. |  3   2015   1   1     15 |
  6. |  3   2016   1   1     17 |
     +--------------------------+
```

Suitable variable names for time-dependent data will have a common prefix and 
a numeric suffix giving time, say `mark` and `2015` and `2016`.